# Improving performance SQL

Tags: sql, db2

Any way to customize below SQL to improve performance where same inner query is running for more than once?

```
DELETE FROM interactionrel 
WHERE  ( from_interact_id IN(SELECT interaction_id 
                             FROM   interaction 
                             WHERE  instance_pk = ?) ) 
        OR ( to_interact_id IN(SELECT interaction_id 
                               FROM   interaction 
                               WHERE  instance_pk = ?) )
```

Comment: That statement is invalid syntax (`where (from ..`). And please format it properly.

Comment: Syntax is correct only I will format it properly.

DELETE FROM INTERACTIONREL 
WHERE 
(FROM_INTERACT_ID IN
(SELECT INTERACTION_ID FROM INTERACTION WHERE INSTANCE_PK = ?)) 
OR 
(TO_INTERACT_ID IN
(SELECT INTERACTION_ID FROM INTERACTION WHERE INSTANCE_PK = ?))

Answer (score 2):

You might try this - although you're going to need to run this against an optimizer:

```
DELETE FROM interactionrel a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM interaction b
              WHERE b.instance_pl = ?
                    AND (b.interaction_id = a.from_interact_id
                         OR b.interaction_id = a.to_interact_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE il 
FROM   interactionrel il, 
       interaction 
WHERE  ( interaction.interaction_id = il.from_interact_id 
          OR interaction.interaction_id = il.to_interact_id ) 
       AND interaction.instance_pk = ?
```

Comment: Thanks for same but its not working. I am using IBM DB2. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=JOIN;